# Node.js dependency installation giving "self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Tags: node.js, ssl, npm, certificate

I am trying to install the dependency `ursa` package. But I get this error:

```
self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

Any idea on how to resolve this ?

I have set the correct proxy settings and was able to download the "node-horseman" dependency as well.

Any inputs will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
>node --version
v6.9.1
>npm install ursa
...\node_modules\ursa>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users
\xxxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1062:38)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:586:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:416:38)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\\\software\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\xxxxxxxxxxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\xxxxxxxxxxx\git\source_code_\ursa
gyp ERR! node -v v6.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN MobPhantom@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN MobPhantom@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

Comment: Something is likely MITM'ing your connection, possibly a proxy or something similar?

Comment: Yes.There is a company proxy.But I have set the proxy url in npmrc file too.Also strict-ssl=false is set.Still I am getting this error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The workaround for this issue is to set the below as environment variable,

NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

Thanks.

Comment: I have looked everywhere for a solution to this and this is the only thing that worked. Thank you

Comment: none of the other soltion works... specially if you're testing  backend on localhost

Comment: This saved me. Was in a rabbit hole of node-gyp windows issues and this was the answer to my problem!